# Cocos2d: the best way to compose an object that will contain several Sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, aggregation, ccnode

I need to create an object that contains several sprites (2 for simplicity: the game object and its' shadow).
I need to compose them into the same class, so having the following questions:

1. what is the best ancestor class to the described one?
   I used `CCNode` for this purpose. I overridden its `draw` method in the following way:

   ```
   - (void)draw {
       [super draw];
       [_item draw];
       [_itemShadow draw];
   }
   ```

and suddenly found that need to change all other CCNode methods in the same way. For ex. change `position`, `visible`, etc. in order to change these properties in both Sprites my custom container aggregates:

```
@interface NBChecker : CCNode {
    CCSprite *_item;
    CCSprite *_itemShadow;
}

@end
```

There is the other way I see - to make both sprites `parent` property pointing to `self`. This should synchronise positions, visibility, etc. for these sprites.

Who has better ideas?
Would like to use aggregation and not sure I'm right in my thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrap the draw code. All you need to do is to add the two sprites as children of the CCNode subclass. Write your logic code in the CCNode subclass and have two ivars for each sprite for easier access (like you already have).

You don't need to draw the sprites yourself as long as they are part of the scene graph.

The sprites will move and rotate relative to their parent automatically. Move the node to move the sprites in unison, etc.

Comment: Hi Stephen! Thank you so much for your answer. We all wait for your book updated to Cocos2d v.3.0

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, I'm not working on an updated version of my book. There may be an update or new cocos2d book from Apress but not from me.